# Delay child view controllers attach in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am trying to find a way to delay the process of attaching child view controllers (via container views on Storyboard). Because there are many container view controllers in my main view, and all of them are hidden (they are shown only after pressing certain buttons) the main view takes almost a second or two to load. Is there any way I can force the child view controllers to attach only after the main view has appeared?

Comment: Check the flow of procees, i think there is some prosess overloding task is there, something relatad to ui, or may be database. First check the view controller lifecycle fliw using breakpoints

Comment: You could load them programatically yourself. On the other hand, if they are shown only after a button press, maybe you could rethink your app structure and use `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController`?

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is that we're using custom animations and UI so it will be a mess trying to change the way UINavigationController works. I was loading them programatically before, I just thought it would be much cleaner using container views. Guess I will have to revert back to programatically.